# How to integrate ccavenue with rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ccavenue

How to integrate ccavenue(Payment gateway) with rails application?

is there any gem or plugin available?

Answer (score 2):

You could use ActiveMerchant - these chaps have integrated it with ccavenue:

http://github.com/meshbrain/active_merchant_ccavenue

Installation instructions are all there in the readme.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register their website and they will provide step by step process for integrating ccavenue

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CCAvenue gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ccavenue).

There is extensive documentation written on how to integrate it. And we have been using it here at [printajoy](http://printajoy.com).